# Is it possible for a c# class to consume a boo macro.ast attribute?

Tags: c#, macros, boo

Is it possible to decorate a c# class with an ast attribute or call a macro and interact with the Boo compiler?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, no. However the [Roslyn project](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2011/10/19/introducing-the-microsoft-roslyn-ctp.aspx) will give you similar functionality, not necessarily for full powered boo Syntactic Macros. But it would probably be possible to do attribute macros with some effort at least.

C# has a long way to go to catch up to Boo still!